# Spring Rest & MVC exception handling

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-rest

I am using `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` to handle all spring mvc exceptions and working perfectly so far, Now with the introduction of REST services, we are started using controllerAdvice i.e `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` to handle the rest exceptions.

In same web application we have both spring MVC & Rest services, After introducing controller advice i.e `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`,  `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` handler is no more getting invoked only controller advice is getting invoked upon excpeptions

Is there any way to limit the controllerAdvice i.e `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` to some url paths i.e starting with /rest/* or *.rest url patterns and all the mvc request (  url patterns)*.htm MUST invoke `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` upon exceptions

Or

any other solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by target the controller advice to only restControllers as below

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = {RestController.class})
public class GroupsRestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    ...
}
```